# Run module after 'Order status gets updated' Action runs

Tags: ubercart, actions

I need to load the order object and run the init function when the order status is updated in Ubercart instead of using `hook_menu()`. How do I hook into the "Order status gets updated" action?  The order state should be "Payment Received."

Does it have something to do with the following code:

```
function uc_order_rules_event_info() {
  $events['uc_order_status_update'] = array(
    'label' => t('Order status gets updated'),
    'group' => t('Order'),
    'variables' => array(
        'order' => array(
            'type' => 'uc_order',
            'label' => t('Original order'),
        ),
        'updated_order' => array(
            'type' => 'uc_order',
            'label' => t('Updated order'),
        ),
    ),
);


function hemo_menu() {
  $items['add_listing'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'init',
  );

  return $items;
}

function init() {
  foreach ($order->products as $product) {
    $array = data_array($product->data['attributes']);

    foreach ($array as $property => $value) {
      $product->$property = $value;
    }

    $product->primary_email = $order->primary_email;
    create_directory_listing($product);
  }
}

function data_array($arr) {
  $array = array();

  foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
      $chars = array(" ", ",", "'", "(", ")", "__");
      $key = str_replace($chars, "_", strtolower($key));
      $value2 = ucwords($value2);
      $array += array("$key" => $value2);
    }
  }
  return $array;
}

function create_directory_listing($product) {
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'directory_listing';
  node_object_prepare($node);
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
  $node->uid = $product->order_uid;
  $node->field_order_product_id[$node->language][0]['value'] = $product->order_product_id;
  $node->field_order_id[$node->language][0]['value'] = $product->order_id;

  if (isset($product->attendee_name)) {
    $node->title = $product->attendee_name;
  }
  if (isset($product->institution)) {
    $node->field_institution[$node->language][0]['value'] = $product->institution;
  }
  if (isset($product->lab_group)) {
    $node->field_lab_group[$node->language][0]['value'] = $product->lab_group;
  }
  if (isset($product->address)) {
    $node->field_address1[$node->language][0]['value'] = $product->address;
  }
  if (isset($product->address2)) {
    $node->field_address2[$node->language][0]['value'] = $product->address2;
  }
  if (isset($product->city)) {
    $node->city[$node->language][0]['value'] = $product->city;
  }
  if (isset($product->state_or_region)) {
    $node->field_zone[$node->language][0]['value'] = $product->state_or_region;
  }
  if (isset($product->country)) {
    $node->field_country[$node->language][0]['value'] = $product->country;
  }
  if (isset($product->phone)) {
    $node->field_phone[$node->language][0]['value'] = $product->phone;
  }
  if (isset($product->primary_email)) {
    $node->field_email[$node->language][0]['value'] = $product->primary_email;
  }
  if (isset($product->zip_or_postal_code)) {
    $node->field_postal[$node->language][0]['value'] = $product->zip_or_postal_code;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for [`hook_uc_order()`](http://api.lullabot.com/hook_uc_order/7) which runs for several operations, including the `update` operation which is:

> Called when an order's status is changed.

Assuming your module is called "hemo" you code might look something like this:

```
function hemo_uc_order($op, $order, $arg2) {
  if ($op == 'update') {
    if ($order->order_status == 'payment_received') {
      // Do something with the $order object.
    }
  }
}
```

Remember to clear Drupal's cache once you've implemented the new hook or it might not get registered.